# Integrating Public Bluemix and Dedicated Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I'm working on a POC for Blockchain and Bluemix (new to both), and the Dedicated Bluemix doesn't have the Blockchain services in it. So, I moved to the Public Bluemix environment but have to pay for the database usage.

Is there any way we can have a connection between the Public and Dedicated Bluemix environments, such that my application is deployed in Public Bluemix and the database is deployed in the Dedicated Bluemix environment?

Comment: This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow because it is not a technical question; its a product availability question. In the future, these types of questions should be published on dW Answers at the following URL: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/
The Blockchain Beta service has a free plan. See: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain/

Comment: I know about the free service. I'm currently using it. But depending on my use case, I was wondering if their was a way to setup connection between public and dedicated bluemix. Will ask the in developer community link provided by you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a technical question...

I can't tell you 100% if this works but you could try this...

From the Public Bluemix create a Secure Gateway connection to a net zone with access to the Dedicated Bluemix, whether that on prem or public dedicated.

On the net zone with access to your Bluemix dedicate you would have to setup a Secure Gateway client, either a Docker image or if you have a Datapower near to your Bluemix dedicated you could use it as your Secure Gateway Client.

Good luck